# Getting Rid of Extra Blank at the End

Tags: c++

I'm supposed to take command line inputs and output them in reverse order. The code I have so far is

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for(int num = argc; num >= 2; num--)
        cout << argv[num - 1] << " ";
    for(int num = argc; num < 2; num--)
        cout << argv[num - 1];
    return 0
}
```

It does its job, but I'm getting an unwanted white space the end of the very last output so for example if I did

./reverse first second third

It would output

third_second_first_

The space after the first is unwanted and I'm having trouble getting rid of it. It's supposed to take as many arguments as I'd like. Is there a simple way to delete the last space?

Comment: Check the condition of your second loop, if you pass any argument to the program it will never run. On the other hand, it will run for a very long time if you *don't* pass any arguments, or until the program crashes due to undefined behavior. And while checking conditions, check the one in the first loop as well. The "simplest" solution is much simpler than you think, and you don't need any extra variables and only a single `while` loop.

Comment: Shorter answer - your first loop prints `third_second_first_`.  Your second loop prints nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to delete it is by not printing it in the first place.

Test to make sure you have at least one printable input and print it. Then for all remaining inputs print out the delimiter followed by the input.

```
#include<iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1)
    {  // Ensure that where is at least one argument to print
        std::cout << argv[argc - 1]; // print last argument without adornment
        for(int num = argc - 2; num > 0; num--)
        { // Print a space and all remaining arguments. 
          // For visibility, I've replaced the space with an underscore 
            std::cout << "_" << argv[num] ;
        }
    }
/* unsure what this loop is supposed to do. Doesn't do anything in it's current state, 
   so I've commented it out.
    for(int num = argc; num < 2; num--) 
    {
        std::cout << argv[num - 1];
    }
*/
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
first second third
```

Output:

```
third_second_first
```

Comment: Wanna explain yourself?

Comment: @RussellGreene  Working on it. Posted way too soon.

Comment: This code exhibits undefined behavior when no parameters are supplied.

Comment: @DrewDormann Yeah, not sure what OP wants with the second loop, so I left it alone. Doesn't add anything to the removal of the training pace so I'm going to clip it.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm pretty sure it was an attempt to handle the printing of the final parameter in a different way (without the space)

Answer (score -1):

For the "simple" solution, I would do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    while (--argc > 0)
        std::cout << argv[argc] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n':
}
```

Do note that it will print the trailing space after the last (first) argument, but unless your professor has a requirement to not have it, or you have an online judge or something similar that disallows it I don't see how it really matters. It's easy to fix though:

```
while (--argc > 1)
    std::cout << argv[argc] << ' ';
std::cout << argv[argc] << '\n':
```